# Is there a way to delete a customer's shipping address from Quickbooks Desktop using qbsdk and qbxml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sdk, desktop, quickbooks

In QuickBooks Desktop, there is a functionality  for multiple shipping addresses available to the customer.
I would like to delete a specific customer's shipping address from QuickBooks Desktop.
So What would be the QBXML request for that So I remove the shipping address from a customer I QuickBooks desktop? The following code to I get list of shipping address from customer wise

```
                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.AppendChild((XmlNode)doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", Common.XMLEncoding, (string)null));
                        doc.AppendChild((XmlNode)doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("qbxml", "version=\\"" + Common.QuickBookVersion + "\\""));
                        XmlElement element11 = doc.CreateElement("QBXML");
                        doc.AppendChild((XmlNode)element11);
                        XmlElement element21 = doc.CreateElement("QBXMLMsgsRq");
                        element11.AppendChild((XmlNode)element21);
                        element21.SetAttribute("onError", "continueOnError");
                        XmlElement element31 = doc.CreateElement("CustomerQueryRq"); //  ShipToAddressDelRq
                        element21.AppendChild((XmlNode)element31);
                        element31.SetAttribute("requestID", "1");
                        element31.AppendChild((XmlNode)this.MakeSimpleElem(doc, "ListID", customerRow.QBListID));
                        element31.AppendChild((XmlNode)this.MakeSimpleElem(doc, "IncludeRetElement", "Name"));
                        element31.AppendChild((XmlNode)this.MakeSimpleElem(doc, "IncludeRetElement", "ShipToAddress"));
                        string xmltest = QBConnection.ProcessRequest(doc.OuterXml);
                        XmlDocument xmlDocument1 = new XmlDocument();
                        xmlDocument1.LoadXml(xmltest);
                        XmlNodeList elementsByTagName1 = xmlDocument1.GetElementsByTagName("CustomerQueryRs");
                        if (elementsByTagName1.Count == 1)
                        {
                            XmlNode xmlNode1 = elementsByTagName1.Item(0);
                            XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlNode1.SelectNodes("//CustomerRet");
                            int index1 = 0;
                                if (index1 \< xmlNodeList.Count)
                                {
                                    XmlNode xmlNode2 = xmlNodeList.Item(index1);
                                    for (int index2 = 0; index2 \< xmlNode2.SelectNodes("./ShipToAddress").Count; ++index2)
                                    {
                                            XmlNode xmlNode3 = xmlNode2.SelectNodes("./ShipToAddress").Item(index2);
                                        ++index1;
                                    }
                                }

                        }
                    }
```